# Thread designed to delete Tkinter Text Widget Content does not operate.

Tags: python, class, widget

Sorry if this is a rather specific problem, but let me try and explain it well.

I've got a text box that a user can add text to by typing in a box and hitting 'Send'.

The problem is that I need to clean out the textbox after fifteen lines have been used.

Here is what I tried to do:

Whenever the user hits send, to add the text to the textbox, it add's a number to a Variable called textlimiter. Because every send button creates a new line as well. I can use a variable to record the number of times something is 'sent' to the textbox.

When the variable exceeds 15, a thread that is watching the variable will wipe the textbox clean.

Thing is, It never seems to work. I've tried asking for help and I got a little from an awesome guy who suggested I rewrite everything into 'frames', so that I can class all my functions, widgets, and variables into one class.

It appears I've got a conflict ion with variable class's. So I tried to set the variable to 'global' inside my class's, and functions using the variable. But that didn't seem to work either.

I can go and rewrite it all into frames I suppose, but I was just going to ask if anyone has a quick fix they can think of here. (I also don't know when the guy can help me once I'm done and if issues arise)

If my question is inappropriate, or somehow not allowed, Tell me and I'll take it down tomorrow when I get up. Sorry if it's bad.

I've got the code here:

```
# [Importing Modules]
from tkinter import *
import os
import threading

#_________________| Setting Variables
global textlimiter
textlimiter = 0


#____________| Defining Functions        


def CONVERT():
    chatbox.insert(INSERT,"You: "+USER_ENTRY.get()+ "\n")
    INPUT_BOX.set("")
    global textlimiter
    textlimiter += 1




#_______| Creating Window |

chat = Tk()
chat.title("Net Send Client [0.4]")
chat.geometry('550x500+200+200')


#________|   Title |

title = StringVar()
title.set("Net Send Chat\n Type in box to send.")
title_widget = Label(chat,textvariable = title, height = 4)
title_widget.pack()

#_______________________| User Input Box|
INPUT_BOX = StringVar()
USER_ENTRY = Entry(chat,textvariable = INPUT_BOX)
USER_ENTRY.pack(side=TOP, padx = 10, pady = 20)

#___________________________________________________________________| Send Button|
send_button = Button(chat, text="Send",width = 20, command = CONVERT)
send_button.pack(padx = 10, pady = 10)


#_______________________________________________________| Text Box Widget |
chatbox = Text(width = 60, height = 15, relief = SUNKEN)
left = Frame(chatbox)
right = Frame(chatbox)
s_start = Scrollbar(right)
s_start.pack(side=RIGHT)

chatbox.grid(row = 0, column = 0, columnspan = 3)
chatbox.pack()

#__________________________________________| Chat Wizard Checks Text Limit|
class Chatwizard(threading.Thread):
    def Chatmonitor():
        global textlimiter
        if textlimiter >= 15:
            chatbox.set(None)
            chatbox.insert(INSERT,"Console: Limit Reached, Chat Wiped" + "\n")
Chatwizard.start


chat.mainloop()
```

As you can see I've tried setting my variables to Global, but nothing seems to change.

If you try running the program, remember you need to enter and send something 15 times for it to supposedly wipe the chatbox.

Thanks for taking a  look if you do. I'm really a little stumped right now.

Comment: `Chatwizard.start` is missing the parentheses at the end. It should be `Chatwizard.start()` if you want to run the thread. Also `Thread`s need to define a `run()` method. Since you have no `run()` method, even if you `start()` the thread, it won't do anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You definitely do not need a thread to monitor the Text widget
  (`chatbox`), because the chatbox itself can tell you how many lines
  of text it contains:

  ```
  numlines = len(chatbox.get("1.0",END).splitlines())
  ```
- Moreover, [Tkinter is not threadsafe](http://effbot.org/zone/tkinter-threads.htm). All GUI widgets should be
  touched by one and only one thread.

---

```
from Tkinter import *
import os
import threading

def CONVERT():
    numlines = len(chatbox.get("1.0",END).splitlines())
    if numlines > 2:
        chatbox.delete("1.0",END)
        chatbox.insert(INSERT,"Console: Limit Reached, Chat Wiped" + "\n")
    chatbox.insert(INSERT,"You: "+USER_ENTRY.get()+ "\n")
    INPUT_BOX.set("")

chat = Tk()
chat.title("Net Send Client [0.4]")
chat.geometry('550x500+200+200')

title = StringVar()
title.set("Net Send Chat\n Type in box to send.")
title_widget = Label(chat,textvariable = title, height = 4)
title_widget.pack()

INPUT_BOX = StringVar()
USER_ENTRY = Entry(chat,textvariable = INPUT_BOX)
USER_ENTRY.pack(side=TOP, padx = 10, pady = 20)

send_button = Button(chat, text="Send",width = 20, command = CONVERT)
send_button.pack(padx = 10, pady = 10)

chatbox = Text(width = 60, height = 15, relief = SUNKEN)
left = Frame(chatbox)
right = Frame(chatbox)
s_start = Scrollbar(right)
s_start.pack(side=RIGHT)

chatbox.grid(row = 0, column = 0, columnspan = 3)
chatbox.pack()

chat.mainloop()
```